# SOA Design Architecture

Tags: soa

Can i check what are the pros and cons of having a generic web service for different service provider and having a separate web service for each service provider?

Is there any articles i can reference also?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is that it is easier to create the infrastructure portion.
The disadvantages are that you now need to write more code to separate the different messages and dispatch them to the proper module for processing. Your code will be more complex and harder to maintain.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498962/contract-first-soa-designing-business-domain-wcf ?

Answer (score 0):

having been down both roads, i would suggest you consider smaller versioned services as opposed ton one large kitchen sink service.

take the unix philosophy of doing one thing and doing it really well.  put a version number on it so you can upgrade with out breaking consumers.  also try to keep the code for each version separate from each other.  once version 1.0 is in production, you don't want to accidentally break a contract with a consumer who may have already coded around your bug.  just publish a new version and nudge your consumers to the upgraded service.

Comment: How about security and performance concerns in relation to maller versioned services as opposed ton one large kitchen sink service.

Comment: @fwrr, I'm not clear on which way you are arguing here.  I would argue that security is a constant across any sized service.  you still have to perform authentication and authorization actions on large and small services.  I think performance is generally won my smaller services if all you are looking at is the time to call and parse one messages.  However if you have to call 10 services to get what you need, perfomance might be equal to one large service.  

it all comes down to your requirements and goals.

Answer (score 0):

BostonBob speaks the truth, service granularity should be scoped to one capability, this aids maintainability in the long run as things live in only one place and are logically cohesive.

As for service operation granularity the sweet spot seems to sit between 3 -5 operations on a service contract, with 12 as the upper limit, if there are more chances are you an decompose it into two useful services.

Here are some practical examples of how to build a SOA

I would suggest you read articles by Thomas Erl and Roger Sessions, this will give you a firm handle on what SOA is all about. And how to partition the services

[SOA Design Pattern](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/SOA-Design-Pattern-WCF)

[Achieving integrity in a SOA](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Achieving-Non-Functional-Requirements-for-a-Service-Oriented-Software-Platform-Integrity)

[Why your SOA should be like a VW Beetle](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/Why-your-Service-Orientated-Architecture-SOA-needs-to-be-like-a-VW-Beetle)

[SOA explained for your boss](http://hubpages.com/_1k9ore6as3b3m/hub/soa-with-wcf)